# How can I clone a repository in which I am developing with someone?

Tags: github

We are a small team doing our own project and we need to somehow add a repository to each participant, so that later we can show what we did, how can this be done correctly?

We tried to google but did not really understand how to do it, leaving just a link like 'I took part in this project' seems to us not such a right decision

Comment: You've got it backwards. Have somebody create a single repository, then add each _participant_ to the _repository_. Ideally you do this before you start writing any code

Comment: But is it possible for project participants to add it to their github projects? So they have a copy?

Comment: Yes, you can fork the repository so that a copy of it appears under your repositories. You can still incorporate changes from your fork back into the main repo, but it's less direct than contributing straight to the original repository

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a central, bare repository and have everyone clone that. Then they push and pull from that central repository to stay coordinated. There are [various workflows](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows) of which the [feature branch workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow) is a good place to start.

Rather than doing this yourself, it's much simpler to host your code on a service such as [Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/) or [Github](https://github.com/). Both offer private repositories for free and many, many excellent additional features.